# HTML5 Server-Sent Events onerror showing up every 3 seconds

Tags: php, html, server-sent-events

I'm new on SSE and I'm following the [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp). I added some code to their example so I can see when the connection is opened and when some error occours. Here is my code:

```
<script>
var source = new EventSource("sse.php");                        
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log("onmessage");           
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";     
}, false);

source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    console.log("onopen");
}, false);

source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    console.log('error '+e.readyState);
}, false);

</script>
```

And my server-side code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

The documentation says that

> A server-sent event is when a web page automatically gets updates from a server. This was also possible before, **but the web page would have to ask if any updates were available. With server-sent events, the updates come automatically.**

But the console shows us the opposite:

[image]

The client-side is requesting a new connection, getting the message, an error is occurring and the connection is closed. This is repeated every 3 seconds. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your server side implementation is not holding the HTTP connection open. So it is reconnecting over and over again.

I don't write PHP but [every example](http://www.howopensource.com/2014/12/introduction-to-server-sent-events/) I've found uses `ob_flush()` in addition to `flush()`.

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: In the example SSE with infinite loop makes no sense. It is again a trivial polling. We just moved the polling form client to server!!!